# How to use relevel in R

Tags: r

I current have one of my R column vector day as

```
Levels: D1 D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 D18 D19 D2 D20 D21 D22 D23 D24 D25 D26 D27 D28 D29 D3 D30 D31 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9
```

Would like to relevel it to

```
Levels: D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 D11 ... D31
```

How do we do that in R with `relevel()`?  Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! May I suggest you to please start by reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you mean that you just want the levels to show up in human-sensible order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to use the `relevel` function, it would be a lot more complicated than needed.  You can do this with just the `factor` function and the `mixedsort` function from the gtools package:

```
> library(gtools)
> tmp2 <- factor( sample( paste0("D", 1:25), 100, TRUE ) )
> tmp2
  [1] D19 D2  D24 D4  D6  D13 D4  D16 D3  D13 D14 D3  D5  D23 D14 D3  D23 D9 
 [19] D4  D19 D15 D10 D19 D17 D5  D21 D15 D22 D1  D9  D13 D8  D25 D12 D6  D23
 [37] D11 D13 D19 D12 D12 D11 D20 D11 D8  D13 D18 D25 D14 D15 D18 D23 D22 D1 
 [55] D4  D20 D13 D7  D3  D12 D9  D8  D10 D13 D2  D5  D1  D13 D14 D13 D4  D2 
 [73] D21 D9  D21 D24 D25 D21 D20 D11 D17 D2  D7  D12 D13 D6  D13 D21 D3  D3 
 [91] D15 D9  D7  D13 D25 D2  D2  D8  D10 D3 
25 Levels: D1 D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 D18 D19 D2 D20 D21 D22 ... D9
> tmp2 <- factor(tmp2, levels=mixedsort(levels(tmp2)))
> tmp2
  [1] D19 D2  D24 D4  D6  D13 D4  D16 D3  D13 D14 D3  D5  D23 D14 D3  D23 D9 
 [19] D4  D19 D15 D10 D19 D17 D5  D21 D15 D22 D1  D9  D13 D8  D25 D12 D6  D23
 [37] D11 D13 D19 D12 D12 D11 D20 D11 D8  D13 D18 D25 D14 D15 D18 D23 D22 D1 
 [55] D4  D20 D13 D7  D3  D12 D9  D8  D10 D13 D2  D5  D1  D13 D14 D13 D4  D2 
 [73] D21 D9  D21 D24 D25 D21 D20 D11 D17 D2  D7  D12 D13 D6  D13 D21 D3  D3 
 [91] D15 D9  D7  D13 D25 D2  D2  D8  D10 D3 
25 Levels: D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 ... D25
>
```

Comment: Thanks Greg.  Just what I needed.